# Add table to textbox in html

Tags: php, html

I have a food recipes site, users are able to submit their own recipes, on the page where you submit your recipes there are textboxes to enter the description of the recipe.

What I need is basically, when users open the page with the form, on the textbox I want to appear a table there (I already have the code for the table). I just don't know where to put that code. I was wondering if I could use value="table code here" for the table to appear in the text box? Or is there another way?

Here's the code of the textbox:

```
<label for="inputPassword3" class="col-sm-3 control-label"><?php echo RECIPE_DESCRIPTION; ?></label>
```

Comment: shout you try CKEditer :D

Comment: why you need it in textbox only,you can keep only table as well on page

Comment: what about table which has inputs as cells?

Comment: That's what I am using but I need the table to appear there so the user just puts the data in.

Comment: @Kobra, maybe something like this : add some button "Add recipe" which will open modal window with table where user can add details of recipe?

Comment: your question is really confusing, i cant understand what u want

Comment: @Adnan I thought it was, my apologies. Basically when the user goes to the recipes submission page, I want a table with cells to appear inside the textbox Did it made more clear?

Comment: Anyone able to help please?

Answer (score 0):

The  tag does not allow you to pass in a  tag. What I would recommend however is creating a  and adding  tags inside of your individual table row's cells.

Ex:

```
<table>
    <tr><td><input type="text" /></td></tr>
</table>
```